# Converting react class component to functional component, rendering perfectly but functionality lost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-class-based-component

I am making a small audio player application and attempting to convert my react class component into a functional component.

The original code for the class component is here:

```
class Player extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
        tracks: [
          {title: "first track", data: track1},
          {title: "second track", data: track2},
          {title: "third track", data: track3},
        ],
        currentTrack: 0,
    }

    }

     changeData(trackIndex){
      this.setState({currentTrack: trackIndex})
    }
  
    render(){
        return <div style={{color: this.props.color}}>
            <h1>Player</h1>
           <AudioPlayer
            src= {this.state.tracks[this.state.currentTrack].data}
            />
            <div style={{color: "green"}}>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.tracks.map((trackElem, index) => (
                       <li onClick={()=> this.changeData(index)}>{trackElem.title}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I have attempted the conversion below:

```
const Player2 = () => {

   const Items = [
          {title: "first track", data: track1},
          {title: "second track", data: track2},
          {title: "third track", data: track3},
    ]; 

    const [activeTrack, setActiveTrack] = useState(0);

    function ChangeData(trackIndex) {
        setActiveTrack({activeTrack : trackIndex});
    }

    return (
        <div >
           <h1>Player</h1>
           <AudioPlayer
            src= {activeTrack.data}
            />
            <div >
                <ul>
                    {Items.map((trackElem, index) => (
                       <li onClick={()=> ChangeData(index)}>{trackElem.title}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Aside from removing some of the props that are associated with styling the logic is basically the same. The only difference is the handling of the current track, I have attempted to represent this by using states.

When rendering the object to a different page it appears to the screen completely fine, the only issue is that the tracks themselves no longer trigger a response in the audio player.

Would really appreciate it if someone could identify anything I've missed in making the conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
const [activeTrack, setActiveTrack] = useState(0);
```

So `activeTrack` is a *number* in state initially. But then you do

```
src= {activeTrack.data}
```

which doesn't make sense - the number doesn't have a `data` property. Another problem is

```
setActiveTrack({activeTrack : trackIndex});
```

Now you're setting the active track to an object with an `activeTrack` property, which is different from the above two formats as well.

Pick *one* way to represent, set, and retrieve state throughout the component, such as the index:

```
function ChangeData(trackIndex) {
    setActiveTrack(trackIndex);
}
```

```
<AudioPlayer
    src={Items[activeTrack].data}
```